# Mysql: Get count of records

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

There are 2 MariaDB (Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.64-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)) tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`phone` int, `calldate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`phone`, `calldate`)
VALUES
    (123, '2020-01-01 10:00:00'),
    (123, '2020-01-01 11:00:00'),
    (123, '2020-01-01 12:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`phone` int, `calldate` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`phone`, `calldate`)
VALUES
( 123, '2020-01-01 09:01:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 09:02:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 10:15:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 10:20:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 10:23:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 11:05:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 11:12:00'),
( 123, '2020-01-01 11:25:00')
;
```

How to get result as :
The calldate of first record from table1 (2020-01-01 10:00:00) is more later than calldate of two records from table2.
Similarly for second one - the count is 5  (from 09:01:00 to 10:23:00)
But  two records from table2 with calldate 09:01:00 and 09:02:00  are already "overlapped"  by first record from table1, so result should be 3 instead of 5.

```
|------+----------------------+-------+
| phone | calldate            | count |
|-------+---------------------+-------+
| 123   | 2020-01-01 09:02:00 | 2     |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 10:23:00 | 3     |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 11:25:00 | 3     |
|------+---------------------+|------+|
```

Also, the calldate in result set should be most last calldate from "overlapped" subset.

Comment: Strawberry, i edited my question

Comment: In order to provide a solid answer i have some questions that i would like to ask. First of all why there 2 tables with the same structure, what is the purpose of having 2 similar tables for inserting phone calls, is there a certain correlation between those 2 tables? Is table1 a reference table? I ask this because the result-set you show in your question can be provided by one query in `Table2` only.

Comment: Peter Darmis,  the tables have differents structure and not are referenced one to other. I ommited some fields as unimportant

Comment: What is table1 needed for then? You have only three records there and all have the same time structure XX:00:00. Is it a scheduler, does it indicate that you want results per hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select t1.phone, t1.calldate, count(t2.phone)
from (select t1.*,
             lead(calldate) over (partition by phone order by calldate) as next_calldate
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.phone = t1.phone and
        t2.calldate >= t1.calldate and
        (t2.calldate < t1.next_calldate or t1.next_calldate is null)
group by t1.phone, t1.calldate;
```

EDIT:

You can follow the same idea with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.phone, t1.calldate, count(t2.phone)
from (select t1.*,
             (select min(tt1.calldate)
              from table1 tt1
              where tt1.calldate > t1.calldate
             ) as next_calldate
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.phone = t1.phone and
        t2.calldate >= t1.calldate and
        (t2.calldate < t1.next_calldate or t1.next_calldate is null)
group by t1.phone, t1.calldate;
```

This will be even less efficient than the window functions version.

Comment: My version of Mysql doesn't support  window functions .

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and use `NOT EXISTS` in the `ON` clause like this:

```
select t1.phone, t1.calldate, count(t2.calldate) count
from Table1 t1 left join Table2 t2
on t2.phone = t1.phone and t2.calldate < t1.calldate
and not exists (
  select 1 from Table1
  where calldate < t1.calldate and t2.calldate < calldate
)  
group by t1.phone, t1.calldate
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hJB9uEzkkAdpaZCtqB7vWz/1).
Results:

```
| phone | calldate            | count |
| ----- | ------------------- | ----- |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 | 2     |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 11:00:00 | 3     |
| 123   | 2020-01-01 12:00:00 | 3     |
```